# Sort slice in golang html/template?

Tags: go, go-html-template

I have a slice like [{0 1} {0 3} {0 2}].
Order is random.
I'd like to output them in order of second argument.
{{range .Slice}} would return them in the order of indexed position.
I would use something like {{range .Slice|sortBy .[1]}} but there is no such thing.

How can I get the range sorted by sub-item and context set to current item (not the sub-item) at the same time?

Expected output:
0 1
0 2
0 3

Actual output:
rows are returned in random order

Comment: Sort it before you pass it to the template, using the `sort` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom template function to do that.

This question has an answer that demonstrates template function: [Go template doesn't work correctly with if and range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256706/go-template-doesnt-work-correctly-with-if-and-range/58256762#58256762)